# How to modify URL in loading page?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

UPDATE: I realize now that in the scenario described below I will need to be careful of infinite loops since the page being redirected to is the same (minus the added param) as the initial page. Does anyone have any experience with that in Webextensions and can offer any advice on how best to avoid these loops?

---

I've written a few Webextensions for Firefox before but it's been a few years (a little out of practise). But a new problem has arisen for which I can see no solution except to write my own Webextension.

How would I modify the URL of a page and add a query parameter? I am specifically trying to modify the URL of Google Docs pages and add the query param `?mode=html`

So for example, a Google Docs URL might look like:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/7Ujfjsd69To7lInXFOdn49nAxLLhfn43fj43JHDTp87/edit

I am looking to create an extension that will modify that URL so it becomes:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/7Ujfjsd69To7lInXFOdn49nAxLLhfn43fj43JHDTp87/edit?mode=html

(Obviously I only want this param appended when the URL being loaded matches https://docs.google.com/document/d/*)

Can anyone give me a pointer on how to start that? What extensionAPI function(s) would I need to use to do that? At what point in the lifespan of the request should it happen etc?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the purpose of having an extension here. Can't you had this by hand? You really need en extension to had this query param?

Comment: This is probably what your are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/update

Comment: Bastien - I *could* add that param by hand...every single time I open a Google Doc from my Google Drive, but that strikes me as a little inefficient, no? I thought, there must be a way to do that programmatically, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** requires "webRequest" & "webRequestBlocking" permission plus host permission

```js
// add a listener for https://docs.google.com/document/*
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(process, {
    urls: ['https://docs.google.com/document/*'],
    types: ['main_frame']
  },
  ['blocking']
);

function process(details) {
  // check it doesn't have mode=html
  if (!details.url.includes('mode=html')) {
    // add &mode=html if URL already has search string, otherwsie ?mode=html
    return {redirectUrl: details.url + (details.url.includes('?') ? '&' : '?') + 'mode=html'};
  }
}
```

Comment: @erosman...thanks. One question before I jump in and try -- will this code only add the query param to the main page URL? (That is the desired outcome.) I imagine the page might request other resources under the 'https://docs.google.com/document/' location...will this code start adding the query param to all those "behind the scenes" HTTP requests also?

Comment: @LordNull `'main_frame'` means the top frame i.e. tab URL or webpage URL, not the other requests.

Comment: Thanks @erosman it worked perfectly. I am going to click the "accept answer" button but just wanted to note the "if" statement just needs an extra paren...just in case someone else tries to use the code. 

Comment: To also match `<iframe>`'s you can also write this: `types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame']`